# Uniswap UniversalRouter/Permit2 integration problem

Tags: ethers.js, uniswap, defi

I'm trying to use the UniversalRouter and Permit2 contracts on Sepolia. I'm trying to swap from UNI to WETH. I get `Error: transaction failed, reason: 'transaction failed', code: 'CALL_EXCEPTION'`

```
//Assemble the route between the input and output tokens. Specify trade type.
const trade = await V3Trade.fromRoute(
    new RouteV3([pool], UNI_TOKEN, WETH_TOKEN),
    CurrencyAmount.fromRawAmount(UNI_TOKEN, inputAmount),
    TradeType.EXACT_INPUT
);

//Set max UNI token allowance for Permit2 contract.
const uniTokenContract = IERC20Metadata__factory.connect(UNI_TOKEN.address, owner);
await uniTokenContract.approve(PERMIT2_ADDRESS, maxUint256);

//Get Permit2 nonce.
const allowanceProvider = new AllowanceProvider(hre.ethers.provider, PERMIT2_ADDRESS);
const { nonce } = await allowanceProvider.getAllowanceData(UNI_TOKEN.address, owner.address, UNIVERSAL_ROUTER_ADDRESS(ChainId.SEPOLIA));

//Generate Permit2 signature.
const permitSingle: PermitSingle = {
    details: {
        token: UNI_TOKEN.address,
        amount: MaxAllowanceTransferAmount,
        expiration: toDeadline(/* 30 days= */ 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30),
        nonce,
    },
    spender: UNIVERSAL_ROUTER_ADDRESS(ChainId.SEPOLIA),
    sigDeadline: toDeadline(/* 30 minutes= */ 1000 * 60 * 60 * 30),
};
const { domain, types, values } = AllowanceTransfer.getPermitData(permitSingle, PERMIT2_ADDRESS, ChainId.SEPOLIA);
const permitSignature = await signTypedData(hre.ethers.provider.getSigner(), domain, types, values)

//Assemble trade.
const routerTrade = buildTrade([trade]);
const { calldata: data, value } = SwapRouter.swapERC20CallParameters(routerTrade, {
    slippageTolerance: new Percent(params.slippagePercentage, 100),
    owner.address,
    inputTokenPermit: {
        signature: permitSignature!,
        details: {
            token: UNI_TOKEN.address,
            amount: inputAmount,
            expiration: MaxAllowanceExpiration,
            nonce: nonce
        },
        spender: UNIVERSAL_ROUTER_ADDRESS(ChainId.SEPOLIA),
        sigDeadline: MaxSigDeadline,
    }
});

//Execute transaction.
const tx = await walletOwner.sendTransaction({
    data,
    to: UNIVERSAL_ROUTER_ADDRESS(ChainId.SEPOLIA),
    ...(value && !isZero(value) ? { value: toHex(value) } : {}),
    from: walletOwner.address,
    gasLimit: 500_000,
    maxFeePerGas: 100 * 10**9,
    maxPriorityFeePerGas: 1 * 10**9,
});
```